# Where do I define an inner struct static object? It seems I can't

Tags: c++, class, static, definition

I know I have to define a static class member outside of the class in the global scope/namespace, otherwise the compiler will complain about missing symbols. So in the following I can't manage to define the inner struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    struct MyInnerStruct
    {
        int notimportant1, notimportant2;
    };
    static MyInnerStruct object1;
};

int main(void)
{
    MyStruct foo;
    foo.object1.notimportant1 = 5;  // Unresolved external symbol, I expected this to happen

    return 0;
}

MyInnerStruct MyStruct::object1;    // Typical definition of a static member
                                    // MyInnerStruct is underlined, saying it's undefined
```

I also tried a forward declaration above it, but it said something about redefinition. Actually I was wondering also, this having to redefine every

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because there no such symbol `MyInnerStruct` in the global namespace, it's inside `MyStruct`. I.e. you need to do

```
MyStruct::MyInnerStruct MyStruct::object1;
```

This works much the same way you define member functions outside the class.

Comment: just to add, seems like "unresolved external symbol" has nothing to do with this and is a separate issue